# EF 4.1 - Stored Procedure Not Inheriting Pending Transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactions, entity-framework-4.1

I've got a integration test that looks like this:

```
using (var tran = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
   try
   {
      // Act.
      var result = controller.Create(something);

      // Assert.
      Assert.IsNotNull(result);
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      Assert.Fail(exc.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      tran.Rollback();
      Connection.Close();
   }
}
```

Now, in that `Create` method, i end up calling a stored procedure which returns **multiple result sets.**

Here's the code to call that SP:

```
var cmd = Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.MySP @SomeParam";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { Value = "test", ParameterName = "SomeParam" });

using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) <--- exception thrown here.
{
   // code to read result sets.
}
```

I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Which i guess makes sense, but i would have thought it would *inherit* the pending local transaction?

I previously had the above code open a *new* connection, but it just timed out due to an apparent lock the pending transaction had on certain tables, despite the read uncommitted isolation level.

Basically, i need to be able to have an integration test which:

1. Opens a transaction
2. Does some stuff, including saving some records to the db, then calling another stored procedure which accesses data which includes the newly created data
3. Rollback the transaction.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: An integration test that uses IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted is unlikely to be very robust (unless you have exclusive access to DB).

Comment: @MitchWheat - so what do you recommend then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
   new TransactionOptions 
   { 
      IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
   }))
```

This doesn't:

```
using (var tran = Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
```

Must have something to do with the fact that `TransactionScope` lives *outside* of the actual Connection, so it wraps all connections that are opened inside of it, whilst the former code opens the transaction with a specific connection.